# Prevent "git push origin -prune"?

Tags: git, git-push

Just narrowly averted an international incident.  One of our developers performed a `git push origin --prune` (instead of `git fetch origin --prune`!)

This resulted in ALL remote branches being deleted on the remote repository (well, all except the current branch).

Luckily, another developer's clone hadn't fetched, so I could re-push all the remote branches.

This seems rather dangerous to me; is there a way to prevent this, or at least make it harder to do?

Comment: You can always recover the state of all branches from the reflog, so it doesn't really seem that dangerous.  The actual commits don't get removed from the object store, only the pointers to the heads.

Comment: @SvenMarnach - yes, I'm aware it was only the pointers to the heads which got removed.  The reflog didn't seem to contain any useful information though.  It only wasn't dangerous in our case because I could recover the branches from another clone.

Comment: The reflog only contains information on branches that have been fetched to the local clone before.  Unless you specify a non-standard refspec, this should be all of them.  Try e.g. `git reflog remotes/origin/master` for some branch that is fetched to your local clone.  If you actually have branches on the server that have never been fetched to any clone (how?), you might indeed lose the head pointers to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the *update* hook in the server-side.

You can find the documentation about it here :
http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks
and here you find more detailed examples:
[An Example Git Enforced Policy](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy)

I think you can write a hook so that rejects more than one branch being deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought the update hook gets called once for each ref being updated - so I think the remote could never know how many refs are being deleted?

Comment: @SteveFolly: While the `update` hook indeed gets called once per ref, the `pre-receive` hook is called once with the complete list of refs being update.

Comment: @SvenMarnach if you write that as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

That depends how you manage authorization.
If you do use [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html), you just need to make sure that standard users do not have the RW+ permission on the repository.

The syntax for the [access rules in gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#rules) indicates that without the RW+, the user will not be able to push any action that would remove anything in the repository.